# Request: Review Queue Activity Differences

Tags: discussion, review, moderation

So, anyone who's been around M.SE very long, and has access to some of the review queues, knows that the review queues are by no means of equal activity (or busy-ness).

Close Votes is always the most active. It's not too much to say that "it's a bear". I can easily do 20 reviews a day, every day, on this queue. I've noticed that of late it's been quite a bit shorter than it was, say, a few months ago, so good work, reviewers!

Late Answers is easily the least active - I might get one review per month on that queue.

In the middle are Suggested Edits, First Posts, and Low Quality Posts.

Reopen Votes is somewhat inactive, but not nearly as inactive as Late Answers.

I've noticed that in some of the less-active queues like Reopen Votes, a number of users are getting nearly 20 reviews a day; but some of those reviewers already have well over 1k reviews in that queue. The effect is to make it far more difficult for a wider variety of people to get experience reviewing those queues. A site as large as M.SE naturally requires an enormous amount of moderation, and it's best to be continually allowing "new blood" into the system.

> So my request is this: if you already have a lot of experience in a review queue, please think twice about reviewing in that queue. For example, I have a good bit of experience in Suggested Edits, First Posts, and Low Quality Posts. I've done almost no reviewing in those queues lately, because I've noticed that those queues simply don't build up. In Close Votes, despite having plenty of experience, I try to do 20 reviews a day when I can, because I've seen that queue build up to 400 - making it less useful than it might be.

[EDIT] I have removed badge language from this post, making most of the comments below less relevant.

Comment: Please don'r recommend game-motivated actions that are detrimental to the health of the site. The main goal of reviewing is not to win badges but instead to improve the quality of the site, Please don't lose sight of that.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Excuse me, but I made it clear that it's far more important to have new reviewers able to review in the queues than to worry about the badges; clearly that is good for M.SE. The badge is just a mile-marker: you've probably learned how to do good reviews in a queue if you have the gold badge in that queue.

Comment: Then what is the point of remarks like "The effect is to make it far more difficult for others to get the badge"?

Comment: A better suggestion would be to encourage reviewers to only review on topics in which they have expertise (e.g. so they can be better judges on sufficient context, how hard it is to get started, dupes, etc). But, alas, the endless pursuit of badges usually thwarts that, and causes many highly rushed poor decisions. **Gamification is the root of all evil on this platform.**

Comment: @BillDubuque: Like it or not, people are sometimes motivated by little goals like that. (Otherwise, why would M.SE even have them? By your argument we should just get rid of them. Psychologists spend an awful lot of time thinking about stuff like that!) If we can leverage little goals like gold badges for the good of the site, why not do it?

Comment: @BillDubuque: I don't agree that gamification is the root of all evil on this platform. The root of all evil is inside people (like me), not primarily in their environments.

Comment: Ok, not *all* evil, there may be an infinitesimal amount that is unrelated to gamification and rep.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I can certainly agree that un-tamed gamification can be a temptation to shoddy work. But I think the reverse can be true as well: tamed gamification (if you want to call it that - I've never felt like M.SE is a game in any way - maybe a better term is "incentivized"?) can lead to better results, and more buy-in from users.

Comment: In my tags there is usually a strong inverse relationship between quality and gamesmanship, i.e. the lowest quality content is usually posted by users who are clearly fervently pursuing rep, badges etc, and the highest quality content is usually posted by those who mostly ignore the game. So I doubt we'd lose much without  gamification. This seems to be supported by data from prior non-gamified platforms such as sci.math, Ask An Algebraist, etc.

Comment: @BillDubuque: You may be right. But then, let me ask these questions: 1. Are those sites still active? (Or how big did they get?) 2. You're drawing an analogy between the badges I'm talking about, which are review badges, and posting-type badges or rep seekers. Are those comparable, or is it an apples-to-oranges comparison? I don't know, I'm just asking the question. 3. I like to provide free math help, or I wouldn't be here (and on Math Help Forum before, and Math Help Boards now, as an admin). But as a helper, you have to go where people want help. Why is M.SE so successful at this?

Comment: Adrian, @Bill is not wrong. The history of the site is spotted with people who acted quite terribly in name of reputation and badges. I think that most long-term users would remember at least one or two incidents of that kind of behavior being brought up on meta. It is true that the site doubled in apparent size, but has it doubled in gravity? Is the hardcore community still in the same proportion? I don't know. And if you add gamified features, you increase the risk of people gaming it, and the core members ultimately giving up on the site.

Comment: All that to say, I agree that we should minimize gamification. But at the same time, I also agree that it is probably a good idea to let the review queues "breathe" in the sense that they shouldn't be dominated by a small handful of users. (In the big queues that's not an issue, the smaller queues are more problematic.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: So I've been a forum administrator for awhile, now. I've seen Math Help Forum go down because of a lack of power distribution: there was one, mainly absent, admin. He didn't want to let go of the reins, and the site basically died because of him. It's still around, but the quality is non-existent. I've been at Math Help Boards now for a number of years, and it has avoided that problem. Indeed, we have very active moderation and administration. For some unknown reason, it has not flourished like I think it should.

Comment: One thing that has certainly helped Math Help Boards is a distribution of power. There are four admins (of which I am one) that can basically do anything that needs to be done to the site. It helps prevent burnout. That's what I'm after, here. I don't see that what I'm asking for in any way increases the "gamification" of the site. I'm simply asking experienced reviewers in some of the less active queues to give others a chance to learn how to review well in those queues.

Comment: Adrian, I've been on the internet for 20 years now, and I've seen communities rise and fall. I've built some from the ground, and I've toppled others. I know very well how delicate is the balance of maintaining a community online can be. And as I said, I agree that having the review queues dominated by a small handful of users is bad. At the same time, I can understand why some users (especially long-term ones) are reluctant to add features that increase gamification.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I don't see why what I'm asking here (which is by no means a new feature), which is to allow more experienced reviewers to let other people learn how to review well, in any way increases the gamification of the site.

Comment: You might as well be correct on this. It's just the way you've phrased your request: by using the badges as a "marker". It makes it seem like it's more of a "You guys, other people also want a gold badge!" which gives this discussion a gamified aftertaste. As I wrote above, I agree with you that review queues should be diversely monitored, and I also agree with Bill that gamification is not good.

Comment: Well, I think you're both reading into this post your previous experiences; I don't object to removing the badge language, and I've done so. We'll have to agree to disagree as to whether these particular badges have a bad effect or not.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Difficulty of getting review badges](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30053).

Comment: Here is also an post older post in somewhat similar spirit about *answering* rather than *reviewing* - [Letting less-reputable people answer questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7178). I'd guess that similar point could be made about several activities that user do on this site.

Comment: I'm glad to see that you removed the game-related context from your question. When you make substantial changes like that and there is already discussion of such in comments it is best to add a note to the answer mentioning that the comments may no longer (directly) apply due to edits. Else many readers may waste time attempting to understand how the (older) comments relate to the (newest version of the) question.

Comment: I appreciate that the question body has been adjusted. Now, I don't know if gamification affects that much for reviews in Math.SE, but on the biggest site aka. SO... it's almost a daily problem of [robo-reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=robo-reviewer)...

Comment: @BillDubuque: Good call - done.

Comment: To provide a dissenting opinion: How bad is it really that a few individuals can keep up with moderation? The power of the other users is not away should the few stop their activities... You could argue about "experience" but an honest assessment of a post is definitely enough for a "good" review in any queue. If OTOH the current reviewers are doing their reviews in a way that is considered bad, this would be something else. But that is not the topic of this meta thread. In summary: Just let the moderation be handled by whoever wants to do it; the daily limits sufficiently ensure the balance.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: But it's precisely your last sentence that doesn't work when the queue is more inactive, like the Reopen queue. At the moment, because the more experienced reviewers appear to be hammering that queue, you'd have to obsessively refresh in order to get any reviews. The daily limits aren't being reached by the more experienced reviewers. There simply aren't enough reviews to go around.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Then my position implies that I am completely fine with this and that this marginal number of reviews does not need special care and attention.